# Mongodb Mongoose change collection at runtime

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, middleware

in nodejs and mongodb, usin mongoose ,

How can I route data to different collection by some logic?

for example: my application use 'insertMany()' to collection 'mycollection'
and I want to have some logic that decide to which collection should it really be insert, sometime it will insert to 'mycollection1', somtime to 'mycollection2' and so on...

I read that there are middleware in mongoose but i didnt succeed to change the collection name

Answer (score 0):

I have created a method that return the mongoose.model:

```js
const Model = collection => {
  return mongoose.model(<name>, <yourSchema>, collection);
}; module.exports = Model
```

in this way, the model change when you change the collection param!
:)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).